# Decrypting HTTPS traffic in Wireshark not working

Tags: ssl, https, wireshark, encryption

I'm running Wireshark 1.8.6 on Windows Server 2008 R2 and attempting to decrypt incoming HTTPS communication in order to debug an issue I'm seeing.

I have my RSA Keys list set up correctly (I think) but Wireshark will not decrypt the SSL traffic for some reason. I've gotten this to work in the past while debugging exchanges with other client systems so I'm wondering if it's something specific with the TLS being used here (i.e. I've read that you cannot decrypt if using Diffie-Hellman but I can't tell if that's what is being used).

I have my RSA Keys list entry as follows:

```
IP Address: 192.168.1.27 (the IP address of the server)
Port: 7447
Protocol: http
Key File: set to my .pem (which I created using openssl from a .pfx containing both the public and private key).
Password: blank because it doesn't seem to need it for a .pem (Wireshark actually throws an error if I enter one).
```

In my Wireshark trace, I can see the Client Hello and Server Hello but the application data is not being decrypted (Right click -> Follow SSL Stream shows nothing).

My SSL log is pasted below -- is there something in here I am missing that will tell me why the decryption is failing? I see a few entries like this that worry me but I'm not sure how to interpret them:

```
packet_from_server: is from server - FALSE
decrypt_ssl3_record: using client decoder
decrypt_ssl3_record: no decoder available
dissect_ssl3_handshake iteration 1 type 16 offset 5 length 258 bytes, remaining 267 
ssl_decrypt_pre_master_secret key exchange 0 different from KEX_RSA (16)
dissect_ssl3_handshake can't decrypt pre master secret
  record: offset = 267, reported_length_remaining = 59
```

SSL Log:

```
ssl_association_remove removing TCP 7447 - http handle 00000000041057D0
Private key imported: KeyID 02:bb:83:4f:80:cf:39:59:39:cd:74:ab:b4:4b:c7:20:...
ssl_load_key: swapping p and q parameters and recomputing u
ssl_init IPv4 addr '192.168.1.27' (192.168.1.27) port '7447' filename 'C:\Users\username\Desktop\Certs\server_cert.pem.pem' password(only for p12 file) ''
ssl_init private key file C:\Users\username\Desktop\Certs\server_cert.pem.pem successfully loaded.
association_add TCP port 7447 protocol http handle 00000000041057D0

dissect_ssl enter frame #2968 (first time)
ssl_session_init: initializing ptr 0000000006005E40 size 680
  conversation = 00000000060056C0, ssl_session = 0000000006005E40
  record: offset = 0, reported_length_remaining = 123
dissect_ssl3_record: content_type 22 Handshake
decrypt_ssl3_record: app_data len 118, ssl state 0x00
association_find: TCP port 59050 found 0000000000000000
packet_from_server: is from server - FALSE
decrypt_ssl3_record: using client decoder
decrypt_ssl3_record: no decoder available
dissect_ssl3_handshake iteration 1 type 1 offset 5 length 114 bytes, remaining 123 
packet_from_server: is from server - FALSE
ssl_find_private_key server 192.168.1.27:7447
dissect_ssl3_hnd_hello_common found CLIENT RANDOM -> state 0x01

dissect_ssl enter frame #2971 (first time)
  conversation = 00000000060056C0, ssl_session = 0000000006005E40
  record: offset = 0, reported_length_remaining = 326
dissect_ssl3_record found version 0x0301(TLS 1.0) -> state 0x11
dissect_ssl3_record: content_type 22 Handshake
decrypt_ssl3_record: app_data len 262, ssl state 0x11
packet_from_server: is from server - FALSE
decrypt_ssl3_record: using client decoder
decrypt_ssl3_record: no decoder available
dissect_ssl3_handshake iteration 1 type 16 offset 5 length 258 bytes, remaining 267 
ssl_decrypt_pre_master_secret key exchange 0 different from KEX_RSA (16)
dissect_ssl3_handshake can't decrypt pre master secret
  record: offset = 267, reported_length_remaining = 59
dissect_ssl3_record: content_type 20 Change Cipher Spec
dissect_ssl3_change_cipher_spec
packet_from_server: is from server - FALSE
ssl_change_cipher CLIENT
  record: offset = 273, reported_length_remaining = 53
dissect_ssl3_record: content_type 22 Handshake
decrypt_ssl3_record: app_data len 48, ssl state 0x11
packet_from_server: is from server - FALSE
decrypt_ssl3_record: using client decoder
decrypt_ssl3_record: no decoder available
dissect_ssl3_handshake iteration 1 type 166 offset 278 length 4253081 bytes, remaining 326 

dissect_ssl enter frame #2972 (first time)
  conversation = 00000000060056C0, ssl_session = 0000000006005E40
  record: offset = 0, reported_length_remaining = 59
dissect_ssl3_record: content_type 20 Change Cipher Spec
dissect_ssl3_change_cipher_spec
packet_from_server: is from server - TRUE
ssl_change_cipher SERVER
  record: offset = 6, reported_length_remaining = 53
dissect_ssl3_record: content_type 22 Handshake
decrypt_ssl3_record: app_data len 48, ssl state 0x11
packet_from_server: is from server - TRUE
decrypt_ssl3_record: using server decoder
decrypt_ssl3_record: no decoder available
dissect_ssl3_handshake iteration 1 type 8 offset 11 length 5212462 bytes, remaining 59 

dissect_ssl enter frame #2973 (first time)
  conversation = 00000000060056C0, ssl_session = 0000000006005E40
  record: offset = 0, reported_length_remaining = 277
dissect_ssl3_record: content_type 23 Application Data
decrypt_ssl3_record: app_data len 272, ssl state 0x11
packet_from_server: is from server - FALSE
decrypt_ssl3_record: using client decoder
decrypt_ssl3_record: no decoder available
association_find: TCP port 59050 found 0000000000000000
association_find: TCP port 7447 found 0000000004FCF520

dissect_ssl enter frame #2990 (first time)
  conversation = 00000000060056C0, ssl_session = 0000000006005E40
  record: offset = 0, reported_length_remaining = 53
dissect_ssl3_record: content_type 23 Application Data
decrypt_ssl3_record: app_data len 48, ssl state 0x11
packet_from_server: is from server - TRUE
decrypt_ssl3_record: using server decoder
decrypt_ssl3_record: no decoder available
association_find: TCP port 7447 found 0000000004FCF520

dissect_ssl enter frame #2991 (first time)
  conversation = 00000000060056C0, ssl_session = 0000000006005E40
  record: offset = 0, reported_length_remaining = 1380
  need_desegmentation: offset = 0, reported_length_remaining = 1380

dissect_ssl enter frame #2999 (first time)
  conversation = 00000000060056C0, ssl_session = 0000000006005E40
  record: offset = 0, reported_length_remaining = 8565
dissect_ssl3_record: content_type 23 Application Data
decrypt_ssl3_record: app_data len 8560, ssl state 0x11
packet_from_server: is from server - FALSE
decrypt_ssl3_record: using client decoder
decrypt_ssl3_record: no decoder available
association_find: TCP port 59050 found 0000000000000000
association_find: TCP port 7447 found 0000000004FCF520

dissect_ssl enter frame #3805 (first time)
  conversation = 00000000060056C0, ssl_session = 0000000006005E40
  record: offset = 0, reported_length_remaining = 389
dissect_ssl3_record: content_type 23 Application Data
decrypt_ssl3_record: app_data len 384, ssl state 0x11
packet_from_server: is from server - FALSE
decrypt_ssl3_record: using client decoder
decrypt_ssl3_record: no decoder available
association_find: TCP port 59050 found 0000000000000000
association_find: TCP port 7447 found 0000000004FCF520

dissect_ssl enter frame #3807 (first time)
  conversation = 00000000060056C0, ssl_session = 0000000006005E40
  record: offset = 0, reported_length_remaining = 53
dissect_ssl3_record: content_type 23 Application Data
decrypt_ssl3_record: app_data len 48, ssl state 0x11
packet_from_server: is from server - TRUE
decrypt_ssl3_record: using server decoder
decrypt_ssl3_record: no decoder available
association_find: TCP port 7447 found 0000000004FCF520

dissect_ssl enter frame #3808 (first time)
  conversation = 00000000060056C0, ssl_session = 0000000006005E40
  record: offset = 0, reported_length_remaining = 1380
  need_desegmentation: offset = 0, reported_length_remaining = 1380

dissect_ssl enter frame #3815 (first time)
  conversation = 00000000060056C0, ssl_session = 0000000006005E40
  record: offset = 0, reported_length_remaining = 8469
dissect_ssl3_record: content_type 23 Application Data
decrypt_ssl3_record: app_data len 8464, ssl state 0x11
packet_from_server: is from server - FALSE
decrypt_ssl3_record: using client decoder
decrypt_ssl3_record: no decoder available
association_find: TCP port 59050 found 0000000000000000
association_find: TCP port 7447 found 0000000004FCF520

dissect_ssl enter frame #2968 (already visited)
  conversation = 00000000060056C0, ssl_session = 0000000000000000
  record: offset = 0, reported_length_remaining = 123
dissect_ssl3_record: content_type 22 Handshake
dissect_ssl3_handshake iteration 1 type 1 offset 5 length 114 bytes, remaining 123 

dissect_ssl enter frame #2971 (already visited)
  conversation = 00000000060056C0, ssl_session = 0000000000000000
  record: offset = 0, reported_length_remaining = 326
dissect_ssl3_record: content_type 22 Handshake
dissect_ssl3_handshake iteration 1 type 16 offset 5 length 258 bytes, remaining 267 
  record: offset = 267, reported_length_remaining = 59
dissect_ssl3_record: content_type 20 Change Cipher Spec
dissect_ssl3_change_cipher_spec
  record: offset = 273, reported_length_remaining = 53
dissect_ssl3_record: content_type 22 Handshake
dissect_ssl3_handshake iteration 1 type 166 offset 278 length 4253081 bytes, remaining 326 

dissect_ssl enter frame #2973 (already visited)
  conversation = 00000000060056C0, ssl_session = 0000000000000000
  record: offset = 0, reported_length_remaining = 277
dissect_ssl3_record: content_type 23 Application Data
association_find: TCP port 59050 found 0000000000000000
association_find: TCP port 7447 found 0000000004FCF520

dissect_ssl enter frame #2999 (already visited)
  conversation = 00000000060056C0, ssl_session = 0000000000000000
  record: offset = 0, reported_length_remaining = 8565
dissect_ssl3_record: content_type 23 Application Data
association_find: TCP port 59050 found 0000000000000000
association_find: TCP port 7447 found 0000000004FCF520

dissect_ssl enter frame #3805 (already visited)
  conversation = 00000000060056C0, ssl_session = 0000000000000000
  record: offset = 0, reported_length_remaining = 389
dissect_ssl3_record: content_type 23 Application Data
association_find: TCP port 59050 found 0000000000000000
association_find: TCP port 7447 found 0000000004FCF520

dissect_ssl enter frame #2968 (already visited)
  conversation = 00000000060056C0, ssl_session = 0000000000000000
  record: offset = 0, reported_length_remaining = 123
dissect_ssl3_record: content_type 22 Handshake
dissect_ssl3_handshake iteration 1 type 1 offset 5 length 114 bytes, remaining 123 

dissect_ssl enter frame #2968 (already visited)
  conversation = 00000000060056C0, ssl_session = 0000000000000000
  record: offset = 0, reported_length_remaining = 123
dissect_ssl3_record: content_type 22 Handshake
dissect_ssl3_handshake iteration 1 type 1 offset 5 length 114 bytes, remaining 123
```

Comment: If you are just working with HTTP/HTTPS consider Charles Proxy, much more user friendly!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> ssl_decrypt_pre_master_secret key exchange 0 different from KEX_RSA (16)

It looks like you're using a DHE cipher suite (at least not a cipher suite with RSA key exchange), which will provide *Perfect Forward Secrecy* and prevent the decryption of these packets, even if you have the private key.

You might be interested in:

- [This Security.SE question](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/14083/2435)
- [*SSL/TLS & Perfect Forward Secrecy* by Vincent Bernat](http://vincent.bernat.im/en/blog/2011-ssl-perfect-forward-secrecy.html)

If this is for debugging, try to turn off the DHE cipher suites.

You should be able to see which cipher suite you're using by looking within the `Server Hello` packet in Wireshark.

---

Newer versions can also use the pre-master secret directly (read "*Using the (Pre)-Master-Secret*" section of the [Wireshark wiki SSL page](http://wiki.wireshark.org/SSL)). This is something you may be able to get from the client side too in some cases. Either way, for this to work, you need to get hold of the pre-master secret from one of the two parties. Here are a couple of links from that section of the Wireshark wiki:

- [Ask.Wireshark: Follow SSL stream using Master-key and Session-ID](http://ask.wireshark.org/questions/4229/follow-ssl-stream-using-master-key-and-session-id)
- [Security.SE: Decrypting TLS in Wireshark when using DHE_RSA ciphersuites](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/42350/2630)

Comment: In my Server Hello I see Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA but then there is a Change Cipher Spec packet that is sent from the client and I can't tell which cipher it wants.

Comment: Although I was never able to determine the exact cipher that was renegotiated, it seems the issue is related to the cipher used. The server I am using Wireshark on is actually a reverse proxy which forwards requests on to a content server via HTTPS. When I run wireshark on the content server, I am able to decrypt the traffic fine. Therefore, I think the issue is related to the cipher chosen between my reverse proxy and the client system connecting to it.

Comment: @bruno could you please have a look on my question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41227491/non-rsa-tls1-2-packet-decryption