# Python decrypt TLS traffic

Tags: python, encryption, tcp, ssl-certificate

I'm trying to decode SIP TLS v1.0 traffic which uses a known port (TCP 5061).
I do have access to my private key to extract the information (TCP raw data)
I have created my code to access TCP traffic and I can read that info right now.

```
packet = socket.recv(sipLocatorConfig.NETWORK_TCP_MAX_SIZE)
```

My goal is to be able to read encrypted traffic (which I can already) and decrypt it with my private key so I can analyze it after that.
How to convert TLS to TCP/raw data? I was able to start SSL Server, but how to parse raw data using SSL library.

```
import socket
from OpenSSL import SSL

context = SSL.Context(SSL.SSLv23_METHOD)
context.use_privatekey_file('key')
context.use_certificate_file('cert')

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s = SSL.Connection(context, s)
s.bind(('', 12345))
s.listen(5)

(connection, address) = s.accept()
while True:
    print repr(connection.recv(65535))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing a python script to decrypt the raw capture is a huge task. I suggest you give wireshark a try, it is a graphical network analyzer that can already [decrypt SSL / TLS](http://blogs.technet.com/b/nettracer/archive/2013/10/12/decrypting-ssl-tls-sessions-with-wireshark-reloaded.aspx) when you have the key.

Keep in Mind: Perfect forward secrecy can prevent decryption in both wireshark and scripts. See [Decrypting HTTPS traffic in Wireshark not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15814999/decrypting-https-traffic-in-wireshark-not-working-and-not-sure-why)